# AWS SDK in node js - Get object from sub directory

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I'm using the aws-sdk for Nodejs and I'm trying to get an object that's located in a sub-directory.
But I don't get any files back.

The file path is: `mybucket/subfoldername/file.txt`

```
getObject = function getListObjects(bucketName, bucketPath, fileName) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let params = {Key: fileName, Bucket: bucketName+bucketPath};
    s3.getObject(params, function (error, data) {
        if (error){
            console.log(`Can't connect to S3. S3 Path = [${fileName}] to Bucket = [${params.Bucket}]`, error);
            return reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log(`Found files in S3. S3 Path =[${fileName}] to Bucket = [${params.Bucket}]`);
            return resolve(data.Contents);
        }
    });
});
```

};

The arguments I pass are:

```
bucketName: "mybucket"
bucketPath: "/subfoldername"
fileName: "file.txt"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Key`argument should include the "path" string, too, as S3 bucket files are referenced by its complete path:

```
let params = { Key: `${bucketPath}/${fileName}`, Bucket: bucketName };
```

I've taken the liberty of using template quotes there (``). Also, notice how I've added a "/" separator, please check that it's not already included in `bucketPath`.

Comment: Thanks it works! one more thing, I get the the object back but it's in a buffer, the file itself is a csv file. How can make the conversion?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it: save as file? Stream back to HTTP client?

Comment: I would like to check some of it's columns and values.

Comment: I think you'd agree with me that the task of parsing a CSV file would deserve it's own separate question, wouldn't you?.

Comment: Posted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493311/aws-sdk-getobject-convert-returned-file-from-ascii-buffer-to-json-csv