# AWS SDK - getObject convert returned file from ASCII buffer to json/csv

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I'm using the aws-sdk for Nodejs, and I'm getting an object back from AWS bucket in the form of a buffer, like so:
[31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0 ....]

The original object located in the bucket is in csv format, can I convert the buffer to a usable format like csv or json?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily, here's an example:

```
s3.getObject(params, function (error, data) {
  if (error) {
    throw error
  } else {
    // Convert the provided array to a string. You can save it as CSV if you want
    const csvString = data.Body.toString('utf-8')
    // Split the string into CSV lines
    const csvLines = csvString.split(/\r|\n/)
    // Iterate CSV lines
    csvLines.forEach(line => {
      // Extract CSV line values
      const [ value1, value2, value3 ] = line.split(',')
      // Do something with those values
      console.log(value1, value2, value3)
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have JSON in your S3 bucket.
Heres a sample where you can read the JSON and parse it as an object

```
const options = {
  BucketName : 'myBucket',
  ObjectName : 'a/b/c.json',
  ResponseContentType: 'application/json'
};

s3.getObject(options, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error: %s %s", err, err.stack);
  } else {
    const fetchedObj = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: The ```toString()``` method has not been called on the excerpt:

```var fetchedObj = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString());```